# How don't allow for user forward messages from private Telegram channel

Tags: python, api, telegram

I have a private channel in Telegram. It's possible to block forward messages from channel for members. Maybe it's possible with bot? Or maybe you can describe how I can secure my content?

Answer (score 1):

That is a big question.

There are a lot of Telegram bots out there on the web.. That can do all kind of stuff.

Other than that, Telegram itself offers a pretty diverse API, you should check it over [here](https://core.telegram.org/api).

Comment: As I see in network it`s impossible to block forwarding messages from private channels((

Comment: So my guess is, that if the Telegram's API won't allow it, it will be very hard or even impossible to do that.
And again, I guess that you can do a simple check, and see if you are sure that there isn't any other what that the API can do it, or check if one of the Telegram's bots can do something similar.

Comment: Is there an API/bot thet can notify me if someone forward a message out of my private channel.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **protect_content= True** parameter in send_message , copy_message & forward_message functions . This will not allow anyone to forward the message or file to anyone . Also in desktop versions of telegram , user's can't even download (if you have sent a audio,video or other file).